# Deploying spring boot on JBOSS EAP 6.1

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy a jar on Jboss 6.1 EA. I had build the jar file.

I am unable to access the page `http://localhost:8080/$YOURAPP/hello/World`, because I get a 404 error. I replaced the `$YOURAPP` with the name of the war file. I do not get any errors while starting jboss, it shows the war is getting deployed.

Comment: Why not use tomcat - thats the benefit of spring isn't it. No need for an app server ?

Answer (score 5):

You will definitely need a `.war` file for JBoss because a (fat) `.jar` file will not work.
For JBoss, you will also need a `jboss-web.xml` descriptor file in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` file containing the context root of your application.

For example:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>YOUR_APP_ROOT</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

After that, you will need to set one more Spring Boot property to make this work on JBoss EAP 6:

```
server.servlet-path = /*
```

This is due to a quirk in JBoss itself, if you don't have this property set to `/*` it will not work.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37687925/993417) and [here](https://ilya-murzinov.github.io/articles/spring-boot-jboss/)