# Spring boot return error 404 in Jboss

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss

I have a sample Spring boot application. It works in Tomcat server but when i generate a war and deploy it in jboss server(7.1.1) i have 404 error.

this is my restController example :

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
   @RequestMapping(value="/test")
   public String sayHello() {
      return "Hello Spring Boot!!";
   }
}
```

and this is my main class :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
   }
   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
   return application.sources(MainApp.class);
   }
}
```

i added an application.properties file and i added in it this line :

**server.contextPath = /***

my jbos-web.xml is like this :

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!--   this is really not
> needed...   you can just build (or rename WAR file to)
> spring-boot-jboss.war
> --> <!DOCTYPE jboss-web> <jboss-web>   <context-root>/test</context-root> </jboss-web>
```

and finally my pom.xml is as follow :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.boraji.tutorial.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-hello-world-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

i run the applciation by using this url : 
http://localhost:8080/test/test   but a 404 error was returned.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on JBoss EAP 6.4 / spring boot 1.5 and what fixed it was to add this property

```
server.servlet-path=/*
```

as explained in this post : [Deploying spring boot on JBOSS EAP 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737129/deploying-spring-boot-on-jboss-eap-6-1)

It worked fine without this property on JBoss EAP 7.1 though.

Answer (score 0):

Your `jboss-web.xml` should be located in `scr/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` then Jboss will use it at the start and use your defined `context-root`.

Answer (score 0):

Add ComponentScan annotation on your MainApp class.
Probably your @RestController annotation was not found by spring component scanner

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.blabla.*"})
public class MainApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve by using below property

```
server.contextPath = /*
```

But, if you want to have root context path for your application then it has to be some string value instead of astrike (which represents a pattern). And, actually this is not allowed. If I used same property while using tomcat server. Tomcat throws below error while registering web module

```
2018-08-23 21:26:58.500 ERROR 13612 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry  : Error registering Tomcat:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/*,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
```

If you are trying to access url as

```
http://localhost:8080/test/test
```

Then, update property file with below

```
server.contextPath = /test
```

Otherwise, don't add this property in application.properties file, and you can access

```
http://localhost:8080/test
```